# Dispatch a pod for each entry in CSV

Tags: argo-workflows

I use Argo Workflows to dispatch lists of jobs defined in a CSV. I accomplish this by chaining a bunch templates together, which involves:

- Breaking up the CSV file into individual JSON objects
- Parsing the JSON into parameters
- Actually passing the parameters to individual pods

The YAML which accomplishes this is:

```yaml
entrypoint: main

templates:
  - name: main
    steps:
      - - name: get-inputs
          # Produces the complete set of work units from the initial input
          template: split-csv
          arguments:
            artifacts:
              - name: csv-file
                s3: retrieve csv from s3

      - - name: process-each
          # Iterates over the a set of work units produced by the previous step
          template: compute-one
          arguments:
            parameters:
              - name: index
                value: "{{item}}"
            artifacts:
              - name: mappings
                from: "{{steps.get-inputs.outputs.artifacts.json-data}}"
          withSequence:
            count: "{{steps.get-inputs.outputs.parameters.length}}"

  - name: compute-one
    # Processes a single work unit
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: index
      artifacts:
        - name: mappings
    steps:
      - - name: get-work-item
          # Retrieves the artifact references that are required to process a single unit of work
          template: get-work-item
          arguments:
            parameters:
              - name: index
                value: "{{inputs.parameters.index}}"
            artifacts:
              - name: mappings
                from: "{{inputs.artifacts.mappings}}"

      - - name: big-compute
          # Where the parameters accessed from the CSV get used.
          template: my-compute-job
          arguments:
            parameters:
              - name: param0
                value: "{{steps.get-work-item.outputs.parameters.param0}}"
              - name: param1
                value: "{{steps.get-work-item.outputs.parameters.param1}}"
              - name: param2
                value: "{{steps.get-work-item.outputs.parameters.param2}}"

  - name: get-work-item
    # From a given JSON array, get the item at `index`, which is expected to be an object,
    # and output the values of its keys to pass as parameters
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: index
      artifacts:
        - name: mappings
          path: /tmp/mappings.json
    outputs:
      parameters:
        - name: param0
          valueFrom:
            path: /tmp/param0
        - name: param1
          valueFrom:
            path: /tmp/param1
        - name: param2
          valueFrom:
            path: /tmp/param2
    script:
      image: stedolan/jq
      command: [sh]
      source: |
        jq -r '.[{{inputs.parameters.index}}].param0' {{inputs.artifacts.mappings.path}} > {{outputs.parameters.param0.path}}
        jq -r '.[{{inputs.parameters.index}}].param1' {{inputs.artifacts.mappings.path}} > {{outputs.parameters.param1.path}}
        jq -r '.[{{inputs.parameters.index}}].param2' {{inputs.artifacts.mappings.path}} > {{outputs.parameters.param2.path}}

  - name: split-csv
    # Given a CSV file, convert each row into a JSON-formatted object,
    # and output the list all resulting objects as an artifact,
    # and the length of this list as a parameter
    inputs:
      artifacts:
        - name: csv-file
          path: /tmp/input.csv
    script:
      image: python:alpine
      command: [python]
      source: |
        from csv import reader
        import json

        with open("{{inputs.artifacts.csv-file.path}}", "r") as f:
          rows = reader(f)
          next(rows)
          data = [ {"param0": r[0], "param1": r[1], "param2": r[2]} for r in list(rows) ]

        with open("{{outputs.artifacts.json-data.path}}", "w") as f:
          f.write(json.dumps(data))

        with open("{{outputs.parameters.length.path}}", "w") as f:
          f.write(str(len(data)))
    outputs:
      parameters:
        - name: length
          valueFrom:
            path: /tmp/length
      artifacts:
        - name: json-data
          path: /tmp/data.json
```

Is there a way to do this with fewer steps? I keep needing to paste some form of this into other Argo workflows I create. Is there some way to modularize it and import it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `get-work-item` to iterate through the JSON.

````
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
spec:
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: s3-bucket
      - name: input-csv
      - name: output-path

  volumes:
    - name: workdir
      emptyDir: {}

  entrypoint: main

  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: get-inputs
            # Produces the complete set of work units from the initial input
            template: split-csv
            arguments:
              artifacts:
                - name: csv-file
                  s3:
                    endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
                    bucket: "{{workflow.parameters.s3-bucket}}"
                    key: "{{workflow.parameters.input-csv}}"

        - - name: process-each
            # Iterates over the a set of work units produced by the previous step
            template: big-compute
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: param0
                  value: "{{item.param0}}"
                - name: param1
                  value: "{{item.param1}}"
                - name: param2
                  value: "{{item.param2}}"
            withParam: "{{steps.get-inputs.outputs.parameters.json-data}}"
    
    - name: split-csv
      # Given a CSV file, convert each row into a JSON-formatted object,
      # and output the list all resulting objects as an artifact,
      # and the length of this list as a parameter
      inputs:
        artifacts:
          - name: csv-file
            path: /tmp/input.csv
      outputs:
        parameters:
          - name: json-data
            valueFrom:
              path: /tmp/data.json
      script:
        image: python:alpine
        command: [python]
        source: |
          from csv import reader
          import json
          from pathlib import Path
          import os

          with open("{{inputs.artifacts.csv-file.path}}", "r") as fi:
            rows = reader(fi)
            next(rows)
            data = [{"param0": r[0], "param1": r[1], "param2": r[2]} for r in list(rows)]

          with open("{{outputs.parameters.json-data.path}}", "w") as fi:
            json.dump(data, fi)

    - name: big-compute
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: param0
          - name: param1
          - name: param2
      outputs:
        artifacts:
          - name: collected-outputs
            path: /workdir/out
            archive:
              none: {}
            s3:
              endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
              bucket: "{{workflow.parameters.s3-bucket}}"
              key: "{{workflow.parameters.output-path}}"
      script:
        image: fedora:33
        command: [bash]
        source: |
          set -xe

          mkdir /workdir/out && cd /workdir/out
          echo "{{inputs.parameters.param0}},{{inputs.parameters.param1}},{{inputs.parameters.param2}}" \
                > {{inputs.parameters.param0}}_{{inputs.parameters.param1}}_{{inputs.parameters.param2}}

        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 30Mi
            cpu: 20m
          limits:
            memory: 30Mi
            cpu: 20m
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workdir
            mountPath: /workdir
```
````